# Rough estimate of number of bad indices?

Tags: probability, geometry, random, sampling

Suppose I have $n$ pairs of points in a plane $P = \{(x_i,y_i)\}_{i=1}^n$ in a plane. Let $X^2=\sum_{i}x_i^2$ and $Y^2=\sum_{i}y_i^2$. Further assume that $Y^2 \leq \epsilon^4X^2$ for some error parameter $0<\epsilon\leq1$.

Define $GOOD = \{i\in[n] : y_i^2 \leq \epsilon x_i^2\}$, and $BAD= [n]-GOOD$. Since sum of squares of y-coordinate is "very" small compared to  sum of squares of x-coordinates, I think there should not be lots of indices in $BAD$ set.

Clearly $\vert BAD\vert < n$, i.e not all points are bad. **Is there a sharper upper bound other that the aforementioned obvious bound?**

My goal is to show that if I sample a point uniformly from $P$, then it should not land in $BAD$ set with high probability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No, there is no sharper bound.**

Indeed, you can make $n-1$ of the points bad and then adjust the final point to be extremely good to make $Y^2\leq \epsilon^4 X^2$. The reason this is possible is that the latter inequality only involves aggregate quantities.

More explicitly, fix any values for $x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1}$ and let $y_i=2x_i$ for $i=1,\ldots,n-1$. Then
$$
Y^2=4(X^2-x_n^2)+y_n^2,
$$
so the inequality $Y^2\leq \epsilon^4 X^2$ is equivalent to
$$
4(X^2-x_n^2)+y_n^2\leq \epsilon^4 X^2.
$$
We can choose $y_n=0$ and thus the inequality is satisfied whenever
$$
(1-\frac{\epsilon^4}{4})X^2\leq x_n^2,
$$
which can be arranged by choosing $$x_n^2\geq \frac{4-\epsilon^4}{\epsilon^4} (x_1^2+\cdots +x_{n-1}^2).$$

**In summary,** any set of points $(x_1,2x_1),\ldots,(x_{n-1},2x_{n-1}),(x_n,0)$ with non-zero $x_i$ and satisfying
$$
|x_{n}|\geq \sqrt{\frac{4-\epsilon^4}{\epsilon^4}(x_1^2+\cdots+x_{n-1}^2)}
$$
will have $n-1$ bad points and $1$ good point and fit your condition.

Comment: Fair point. But if I sample a point $p$ with probability proportional to its length, then the probability that the sampled point is BAD is at most $(1+ \frac{1}{\epsilon})\frac{X^2}{Y^2}$.  Changing the ditribution affect the event drastically?

Comment: @SudiptaRoy Of course changing distribution can change the probabilities of events drastically! Anyway, the original question has been answered, to avoid confusing people if you are planning to change the question, better do it in a separate post.

Comment: In my above comment the probanility is $(1+\frac{1}{\epsilon})\frac{Y^2}{X^2}$.  And in your comment the leading expression should be $\frac{4-\epsilon^4}{\epsilon^4}$

Comment: @SudiptaRoy thank you for the correction, I have updated my answer.